# SAP Business Objects 4.2 Integration

Tags: java-8, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I need help on how to migrate our java codes with regards to connecting to business objects. It was recently migrated from version 3 to 4.2. We are using java 8 running on WAS 9. I have tried updating the jars based from the forums that I have read but I am encountering this error.

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: login The exception is of a known origin. (Error: FWB 00008)
                at com.businessobjects.dsws.Consumer.dswsExceptionDocToAxisFault(Unknown Source)
                at com.businessobjects.dsws.session.Session.login(Unknown Source)
                at com.bms.reacts.bobj.BOWSClient.getInstance(BOWSClient.java:138)
                at com.bms.reacts.ui.reports.action.GetDynaReportPromptsAction.getBoWsClient(GetDynaReportPromptsAction.java:674)
                at com.bms.reacts.ui.reports.action.GetDynaReportPromptsAction.execute(GetDynaReportPromptsAction.java:153)
                at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
                at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
                at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
                at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:477)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
                at com.bms.sidetrack.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:103)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:961)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:294)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
                at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
                at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
                at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
                at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
                at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)

Please see below codes:

public static synchronized BOWSClient getInstance()
                                                throws  AxisFault, NamingException, MalformedURLException {

```
                            BOWSClient bowsclient = null;

                            if (bowsclient == null) {
                                            bowsclient = new BOWSClient();
                            }

                            try {

                                            // create connection
                                            Connection boConnection;
                                            boConnection = new Connection(getBoConURL());


                                            int bobjServerTimout =  Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("BOBJ_SRVR_TOUT")) *60*1000;
                                            boConnection.setTimeOut(bobjServerTimout);

                                            // provide authentication credentials
                                            EnterpriseCredential boCredential = EnterpriseCredential.Factory.newInstance();

                                            //username, pwd and urls are loaded from database table appl_parm during login
                                            boCredential.setLogin(System.getProperty("BOBJ_UNAME"));
                                            boCredential.setPassword(ReactsUtil.doROT13Convert(System.getProperty("BOBJ_PWD")));
                                            boCredential.setAuthType("secEnterprise");

                                            if (bowsclient.bowsSession == null) {
                                                            // create session
                                                            bowsclient.bowsSession = new Session(boConnection);

                                                            SessionInfo boSI = bowsclient.bowsSession.login(boCredential);
                                                            bowsclient.bowsSession.resetSessionTimeOut();

                                                            if (log.isDebugEnabled())
                                                                            log.debug("BOWS Conn established successfully.");
                                            }
                            } catch (AxisFault e) {
                                            log.error("Exception message is " + e.getMessage(), e);
                                            throw e;
                            } catch (NamingException e) {
                                            log.error("Exception message is " + e.getMessage(), e);
                                            throw e;
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                            log.error("Exception message is " + e.getMessage(), e);
                                            throw e;
                            }

                            return bowsclient;
            }
```

I am not sure if this is an error on Java or BO. Please let me know the steps on how to integrate it properly.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information in order to get help here.  At least the code that is throwing the error, the full stack trace, and which libraries you're using.

Comment: Hi I have added the code where the error occured and the full stack trace.